# What is the best way to acces language variables in a function?

Tags: php, function, global-variables, scope

Basically, I've included my language file in my page, in that language file are arrays like `$lang['ERROR']['TITLE']`, so my question is: what is the best way to acces those variables in functions?

Comment: @maja not inside a function you can't. You need to use the `global` keyword at the top.

Comment: If you want to know more about standard ways of translating your PHP application, search for "PHP internationalisation", or "i18n" for short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of two methods depending on what you want:

1) Declare a global variable:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['lang'] = $lang;
function test () {
    echo $GLOBALS['lang']['ERROR']['TITLE'];
}
test();
?>
```

This makes it able to be used inside any function.

2) Pass it to the function:

```
function test ($var) {
    echo $var;
}
test ($lang['ERROR']['TITLE']);
```

This only allows for it inside the one specific function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
    $lang = ...;
    function test () {
        global $lang;
        echo $lang['ERROR']['TITLE'];
    }
    test();
?>
```

The `global`-keyword is needed, to tell php that it should look for this variable in the global-scope. Otherwise, `$lang` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `global` keyword at the top of your function to access a variable defined outside the function. Eg:

```
function test() {
    global $lang;
    echo $lang['ERROR']['TITLE'];
}
```

Comment: I think you accidentally put `n` instead of `;`.

Comment: Damn keyboard. Posting from my mobile. I've corrected that now.